# How to distinguish between users and groups assigned to a folder security?

Tags: c#, .net

I wrote a simple code to retrieve security information of a folder
the information contain User and groups and the rights they have on the folder

```
public void GetSecurityRules(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo)
    {
        DirectorySecurity DSecurity = directoryInfo.GetAccessControl();
        AuthorizationRuleCollection Rules = DSecurity.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(NTAccount));


        foreach (FileSystemAccessRule fileSystemAccessRule in Rules)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("User/Group name {0}",fileSystemAccessRule.IdentityReference.Value);
            Console.WriteLine("Permissions: {0}", fileSystemAccessRule.FileSystemRights.ToString());
        }
    }
```

In the line `fileSystemAccessRule.IdentityReference.Value` I got both Users and Groups but how can i know if the value represent a user or a group?

Comment: Related (but in VB.NET): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464821/how-do-i-check-if-an-ntaccount-object-represents-a-group-or-a-user

Comment: did you get any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, the CLR does not expose this information. You will have to p/invoke [`LsaLookupSids`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms721799.aspx) manually and examine the SID_NAME_USE value it will return. CLR calls this function too in order to translate SIDs to account names, but it throws away the SID_NAME_USE values. For code, break out your Reflector, open mscorlib and see how the internal `TranslateToNTAccounts` function in `System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier` works.

As an alternative, if you are not going to do such lookups repeatedly, it might be easier to use WMI — query a [`Win32_Account`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394061.aspx) by SID and examine the SIDType member.

Comment: any code sample? and if the users or group is from active directory do i have to run the check against LDAP or there is better way?
thanks

Comment: You won't have to, `LsaLookupSids` will do that for you.